# Can one find a bounded sequence in $l^2$ which contains no Cauchy sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there a bounded sequence in $l^2= \{a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} |\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k|^2  < \infty \}$  which contains no Cauchy subsequence?

Comment: Yes. For example, take the sequence $\{e_i\}$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard unit vector.

Comment: And, I presume you meant "which contains no Cauchy subsequence".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $e_n$ be the vector in $\ell_2$ whose $i$'th coordinate is $1$ if $i=n$ and $0$ otherwise. Note $\Vert e_n\Vert=1$ for each $n$. $(e_n)$ is bounded.

It's not hard to verify that $\Vert e_n-e_m\Vert=\sqrt2$ whenever $n\ne m$. From this it follows that no subsequence of $(e_n)$ is Cauchy.

(More generally, such a sequence can be found in any infinite dimensional normed space, using Riesz' Lemma. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Some_consequences)).